# Apache camel copy file between directories

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to apache camel and spring boot. I am writing an application where i need to transfer a file from a folder to jms queue. But before that i am trying to transfer the file from one folder to another, which is not happening. On running the application as spring boot application the input folder gets created. If a paste the file in this folder, the destination folder is not formed and the log statements are also not appearing. This is how I added the route:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CamelApplication extends FatJarRouter {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:input?noop=true")
        .log("Read from the input file")
        .to("file:destination")
        .log("Written to output file");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work, and it does work for me, perhaps you haven't refreshed your workspace in your IDE, if that's how you're tracking the progress.

**EDIT**

I see now what's wrong with your configuration - you probably don't have spring-boot-starter-web on your classpath so your main method does not get blocked and exits instantly.

You should remove the main method from `CamelApplication` and add this entry to `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.sources = com.example.CamelApplication
```

Or, you can change your main method to run `CamelSpringBootApplicationController`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CamelApplication extends FatJarRouter {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        CamelSpringBootApplicationController applicationController =
                applicationContext.getBean(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.class);
        applicationController.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:input?noop=true")
                .log("Read from the input file")
                .to("file:destination")
                .log("Written to output file");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add this to your pom.xml to force an embedded Tomcat to start and block your main method:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the dependency for spring-boot-starter-web and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

add to application.properties to keep the JVM running

`camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true`